# What equipments and software are used to record, edit, and publish SO podcast?

Tags: discussion, podcast

In the podcast, Joel often mentions his podcast recording equipments and editing software. As of now, what equipments and software are used to record, edit, and publish SO podcast?

I enjoy listening to the podcast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered here

[What Tools Are Used to Capture & Produce the Stack Overflow Podcasts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9626/what-tools-are-used-to-capture-produce-the-stackoverflow-podcasts)