# What Tools Are Used to Capture & Produce the Stack Overflow Podcasts?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, podcast, technology

First, the podcast content is improving. I'm finding it more and more intriguing in the more recent shows.

I'm interested in how you are capturing and producing the casts. On one of the casts it became clear you were using Skype to communicate with each other, but the audio quality is way too good for skype, so I'm guessing you are doing local recordings and then combining them. Can you give details, like what tools you are using and how you are combining and processing the files? How much automation have you been able to achieve, and how?

Answer (score 5):

[The link Rob posted](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/PodcastEquipment.html) is pretty up to date. I've since added a little preamp for the mic, but that's a trivial change.

Yes, it's still skype. Because we have no relays, very low packet loss, and low latency between Jeff's home in California and my office in New York, Skype sound quality is exceptional.

Editing is done with Audacity. As time goes on, I get a little bit fancier... lately I've taken to using the automatic noise reduction feature in Audacity 1.3 beta to eliminate the last bits of background noise which I think come from the dirty power going into all the analog gear. Under normal circumstances I can edit a show in about 5-10 minutes depending on how many deletes are needed. Last week, for example, a shoddy internet connection caused the skype call to drop twice, but this is relatively rare.

Comment: Joel, has your podcast setup changed at all over the last year?

Answer (score 3):

Joel made a recent post regarding this subject on his blog; see [How the StackOverflow Podcast is produced](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/PodcastEquipment.html).

Answer (score 1):

An update has been posted on the blog (August 2011): [The SE Podcast Setup](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-se-podcast-setup/)